# Alembic - Remove legacy table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, drop-table

I am junior dev, I am new at a project. I have to delete a legacy table.

I found it in a migration (created with Alembic):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'customer_data',
        # Columns
        sa.Column('customer_id', UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column('name', sa.String(), nullable=False),
   )

def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('customer_data')
```

What should I do to drop this table? Should I remove this code from the migration, remote the migration file, or create a new migration where the upgrade performs the drop table? If the last option is correct, the downgrade should do the creation?

Can I create the migration manually or I need to execute something in the command line?

Comment: Have you studied the [Alembic tutorial](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)? Essentially, you need to create a new revision because tools like Alembic provide a history of changes to the database structure. However, if you are certain that you'll never want the "customer_data" table back again then your revision could `op.drop_table('customer_data')` in the `upgrade()` method and just do nothing in the `downgrade()` method. You probably should check with your team to see how they want you to proceed.

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson!!! I am reading the Alembic tutorial! But thank you for the advice on the approach